# Trusting the Heroku Router with Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, heroku

I'm trying to trust Heroku load-balancer to get correct remote address but unfortunately I can't make it work. The only thing I did is using environment variables and added `heroku config:set TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16`.

As you see, the `REMOTE_ADDR` is still the private IP address of the loadbalancer, not the real IP adress.

**// EDIT 1**

According to Heroku documentation, I have to trust the loadbalancer so I can have the correct REMOTE_ADDR (here it should be 92.167.83.207 instead of 10.30.214.102)
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-symfony4#trusting-the-heroku-router

According to Symfony documentation, the configuration looks approximatly the same
https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html#but-what-if-the-ip-of-my-reverse-proxy-changes-constantly

**// END EDIT 1**

Here I put some dumps:

```php
// public/index.php

// ...

if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    dump(explode(',', $trustedProxies));

    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}

// ...
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="default")
     */
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        dd($request->server->all());

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'DefaultController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

And there are the results:

```
^ array:4 [▼
  0 => "127.0.0.0/8"
  1 => "10.0.0.0/8"
  2 => "172.16.0.0/12"
  3 => "192.168.0.0/16"
]
```

```
^ array:69 [▼
  ...
  "TRUSTED_PROXIES" => "127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16"
  ...
  "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT" => "443"
  "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" => "https"
  "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" => "92.167.83.207"
  ...
  "SERVER_NAME" => "************.herokuapp.com"
  "SERVER_PORT" => "8706"
  "SERVER_ADDR" => "172.18.163.74"
  "REMOTE_PORT" => "15593"
  "REMOTE_ADDR" => "10.30.214.102"
  ...
]
```

Comment: And why do you expect `REMOTE_ADDR` would have the client's IP address? The env var you are looking for is `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`.

Comment: Can you explain further what **exactly** is not working?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I give more information:
According to Heroku documentation, I have to trust the loadbalancer so I can have the correct REMOTE_ADDR (here it should be 922.167.83.207 instead of 10.30.214.102)
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-symfony4#trusting-the-heroku-router
According to Symfony documentation, the configuration looks approximatly the same
https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html#but-what-if-the-ip-of-my-reverse-proxy-changes-constantly
(Edited my original post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Use `$request->getClientIp()` not `$request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')`.

Ok, I understood. The configuration was good. It's just that, if you want to get IP of the client, you should not use `$request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')` (this call will bypass trusted proxies configuration) as you would do with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. But use `$request->getClientIp()` instead. I saw nothing in both documentations about that.